# jQuery remove content when it passed then append at the end

Tags: jquery, scrollto

Hi I want to know how to remove passed content when scrolled down, then add the content back to the bottom.

Example here the the first unordered list was passed it will remove and go back at the bottom.

Please let me know how to do it in jQuery as I can't find any similar plugin. There is infinite scroll plugin but it doesn't remove the passed contents.

TIA

```css
html,body{margin:0; padding:0}
li{list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.content {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  height: 250px;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="unordered">

  <li class="header" style="z-index: 1000;">
      <h3>Header1</h3>
  </li>

  <li class="header2" style="background:#666;z-index: 1000;height: 50px;">
      <h5 style="margin: 0;">Header2</h5>
  </li>


  <li class="content">
    Contents
  </li>

</ul>


<ul class="unordered">

  <li class="header" style="z-index: 1000;">
      <h3>Header1</h3>
  </li>

  <li class="header2" style="background:#666;z-index: 1000;height: 50px;">
      <h5 style="margin: 0;">Header2</h5>
  </li>


  <li class="content">
    Contents
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? What's your intention with this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although I don't know why you need this, but here's the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var firstElem = $('body > :first-child');
    var firstElemHeight = firstElem.outerHeight();
    if (scrollPos > firstElem.offset().top + firstElemHeight) {
        firstElem.insertAfter('body > :last-child');
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollPos - firstElemHeight);
    }
});
```

A live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pq5wLboy/1/

Comment: Yes, it's complicated to explain it but this is actually what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!